# Admob Banner ANR - Android 8.1 (SDK 27)

Tags: android, crash, admob, google-play-console

I'm facing an admob banner ANR appears in my Google Play developer console.
The ANR happens only to users with android version 8.1 (SDK 27).
Any one manage to solve this ANR?

I'm using the most updated versions of firebase and admob ads.

If you need some more of my code, let me know and I will share it with you..

Stack trace:

```
  #00  pc 000000000013eba6  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DexFile::FindClassDef(art::dex::TypeIndex) const+33)
  #00  pc 00000000001510ad  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DexFileVerifier::CheckInterClassDefItem()+964)
  #00  pc 00000000001521c3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DexFileVerifier::CheckInterSectionIterate(unsigned int, unsigned int, art::DexFile::MapItemType)+366)
  #00  pc 000000000014ac11  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DexFileVerifier::Verify()+132)
  #00  pc 000000000014aaa1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DexFileVerifier::Verify(art::DexFile const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, char const*, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+120)
  #00  pc 000000000013de71  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DexFile::OpenOneDexFileFromZip(art::ZipArchive const&, char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*, art::DexFile::ZipOpenErrorCode*)+616)
  #00  pc 000000000013d8e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DexFile::OpenAllDexFilesFromZip(art::ZipArchive const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<art::DexFile const, std::__1::default_delete<art::DexFile const>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<art::DexFile const, std::__1::default_delete<art::DexFile const>>>>*)+268)
  #00  pc 000000000013d5dd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DexFile::OpenZip(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<art::DexFile const, std::__1::default_delete<art::DexFile const>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<art::DexFile const, std::__1::default_delete<art::DexFile const>>>>*)+276)
  #00  pc 000000000013d3a9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DexFile::Open(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<art::DexFile const, std::__1::default_delete<art::DexFile const>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<art::DexFile const, std::__1::default_delete<art::DexFile const>>>>*)+376)
  #00  pc 000000000031efc7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::OatFileManager::OpenDexFilesFromOat(char const*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*, art::OatFile const**, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>>*)+3890)
  #00  pc 00000000002ee249  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DexFile_openDexFileNative(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jstring*, int, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+96)
  #00  pc 00000000000519fb  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-libart.oat (Java_dalvik_system_DexFile_openDexFileNative__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2ILjava_lang_ClassLoader_2_3Ldalvik_system_DexPathList_00024Element_2+194)
  at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative (Native method)
  at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile (DexFile.java:353)
  at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init> (DexFile.java:100)
  at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init> (DexFile.java:74)
  at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile (DexPathList.java:374)
  at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements (DexPathList.java:337)
  at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init> (DexPathList.java:157)
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init> (BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init> (PathClassLoader.java:64)
  at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader (ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
  at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader (ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
  at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader (ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
  at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader (ApplicationLoaders.java:35)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked (LoadedApk.java:693)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader (LoadedApk.java:727)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.getClassLoader (ContextImpl.java:300)
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass (WebViewFactory.java:394)
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider (WebViewFactory.java:194)
  at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance (CookieManager.java:39)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.v.k (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204204100@204204100000.336078696.336078696:2)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.actions.h.<init> (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204204100@204204100000.336078696.336078696)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.banner.z.a (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204204100@204204100000.336078696.336078696:5)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.shim.f.I (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204204100@204204100000.336078696.336078696:27)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.shim.f.e (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204204100@204204100000.336078696.336078696)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.shim.y.e (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204204100@204204100000.336078696.336078696)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.au.bx (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204204100@204204100000.336078696.336078696:80)
  at gg.onTransact (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204204100@204204100000.336078696.336078696:4)
  at android.os.Binder.transact (Binder.java:627)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzgw.zza
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxi.zza
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzze.zza
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd
  at com.kingim.managers.AdsManager.createAndLoadBannerAd (AdsManager.java:100)
  at com.kingim.activities.GameActivity.initActivityView (GameActivity.java:99)
  at com.kingim.activities.BaseActivity.onCreate (BaseActivity.java:119)
  at com.kingim.activities.BasePurchasesActivity.onCreate (BasePurchasesActivity.java:22)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6999)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6990)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2731)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2856)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1589)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6494)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:439)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Same problem, I’m using unity AdMob plugin (5.4.0)

Comment: could you able to find anything?